# 100 doors help using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby and took a stab at the 100 doors problem and can't seem to get my code to work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? And here is the problem for anyone who needs a refresher or hasn't seen it before: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/100_doors#Ruby

```
def door_change (door_num)
    if door_num == true
        door_num = false
    else
        door_num =  true
    end
end

def pass_doors (array,round)
    i=round - 1
    while i <= array.length
        array[i]=door_change(array[i])

        i=i+round
    end
    return array
end


doors = Array.new(100,false)

round_counter = 1

while round_counter <= 100
    pass_doors(doors,round_counter)
    round_counter += 1
end



for i in doors
    puts i
end
```

Comment: your door_change does not modify the array, try `array[i] = door_change(array[i])`

Comment: Why use a separate function for swapping the boolean value? Try `array[i] = !array[i]`. Also, you'll need to overwrite `doors` with the return value of `pass_doors` after each pass.

Comment: @Rge28 Think about what's the index number of the last element of an array (first one is 0). Next keep in mind that in Ruby when you assign an element to an index after the end of the array, the array is expanded. Tip: put `puts` into your code to see what's going on or use the debugger.

Comment: This worked. Thanks everyone!
def door_change (door_num)
 if door_num == true
  door_num = false
 else
  door_num =  true
 end
end

def pass_doors (array,round)
 i=round - 1
 while i < array.length
  array[i]=door_change(array[i])

  i=i+round
 end
 #return array
end


doors = Array.new(100,false)

round_counter = 1

while round_counter <= 100
 pass_doors(doors,round_counter)
 round_counter += 1
end



for i in doors
 puts i
end

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this code

```
while i <= array.length
    array[i]=door_change(array[i])

    i=i+round
end
```

When i is equal to array.length it is referncing a position not in the array... so `array[i] = door_change(array[i])` is ADDING ANOTHER ELEMENT to the end of the array.

So on the next increment of i, it's still less than or equal to array.length so it does it again... and again... and again...

Change the code to...

```
while i < array.length
    array[i]=door_change(array[i])

    i=i+round
end
```

Comment: Ah, I see I was beaten to the answer!