# 100 Doors with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on the "Rosetta Code 100 Doors" problem and have hit a wall.
I found "[100 doors help using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212494/100-doors-help-using-ruby)" which was of some help, but I still can't get my code to work.

My `toggle` method doesn't work within my array iteration method.

```
def toggle(state)
  if state == 'closed' 
    state.replace('open')
  elsif state == 'open'
    state.replace('closed')
  end
end

def one_hundred_doors(array)
  i = 0
  100.times do
    i += 1
    array.each_with_index.map do |state, index|
      if (index + 1) % i == 0
        toggle(state)
      end
    end
  end
  array.each_with_index { |state, door| puts "Door #{door + 1} is #{state}." }
end

doors = Array.new(100, "closed")

one_hundred_doors(doors)
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "My toggle method, doesn't seem to work within my array iteration method." What does that mean? Descriptions and detail help. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your array creation method. You create it to contain 100 references to the same string:

```
doors = Array.new(100, "closed")
doors.first.replace("lala")
doors # => ["lala", "lala", ...]
```

but you need different strings.

Create it this way:

```
doors = 100.times.map{"closed"}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!